# No route matches [POST] "/index.html" Rails 4 Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Hi I have a problem with my routes I used a devise when I access my url

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

I have problems when I try to register or Login shows me the following error

**No route matches [POST] "/index.html"**

this is my file route.rb

```
 MesaAyuda::Application.routes.draw do


  #para combo subcategoria en subfamilia incidencia
  get 'fam_subcat_incidencias/:id/edit_subcategoria_incidencias' => 'fam_subcat_incidencias#update_subcategoria_incidencias', as: 'edit_subcategoria_incidencias'
  get 'fam_subcat_incidencias/update_subcategoria_incidencias' => 'fam_subcat_incidencias#update_subcategoria_incidencias', as: 'update_subcategoria_incidencias'

  resources :operarios

  resources :fam_subcat_incidencias


  devise_for :users
  resources :perfiles

  resources :nivel_accesos

  resources :subcategoria_incidencias 


  resources :categoria_incidencias

  resources :ubicaciones

  resources :categorias

  root :to => 'categorias#index'



  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

this is my model User

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :perfil       
end
```

Now viewing the source code of the login form or the action log is pointing to ../../index.html.

Because this behavior occurs? I am doing wrong please help me I'm going crazy

```
<form action="../../index.html" method="post">
                <div class="body bg-gray">

                    <h2>Sign in</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

from the my point of view you have to create controller category and in that controller define index method and check it, it may be work